# How to rotate the polarization of photons?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, photonics

What device is used to rotate photons from H to V. Does it change the energy of the photons? I heard about half wave plate?

Comment: 3blue1brown made a series of videos you might find interesting. Here is the first [The sugar water barber pole effect | Optics puzzles 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCX62YJCmGk)

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect

Answer (score 2):

Well you can rotate the plane of polarization by passing them through an optically active solution..

Comment: The standard examples are a solution of sucrose in water and liquid crystal displays.

Comment: Yes and milk too..

Comment: A the rotators sold by optical companies bottles with milk and tea? Surely there are some good crystals doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a half-wave plate. It is a linear device, hence wavelength remains the same.

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: I am not sure it will rotate all photons from a laser. Though the WL is fixed it is not exactly the same for all photons. But the HWL is fixed. Will it rotate only a part of the photons with exactly the same WL as of the HWP and the other photons will be rotated only partially e.g. not from H to V but to 89.9 grade?

Comment: Yes, retardation in a HWP is in general wavelength-dependent. However this is often tolerable because: 1) in a laser, wavelength is pretty well-defined; 2) commercial waveplates are often designed to have a more or less constant retardation over some wavelength range.

Comment: How does it work? Well, you just rotate the waveplate. In practice, if the fast (or slow; doesn't matter) axis of the waveplate is rotated by angle $\theta$ relative to the polarization of the incoming laser, the outgoing polarization will be rotated by $2 \theta$.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care on losing photons, then you can set a series of tilted polarizers that go from the initial polarization to the desired polarization in steps of a small angle change per polarizer. Some photons would be lost but the transmitted photons would have the desired polarization. The smallest the angle the higher the probability that most photons get transmitted.

[image: Example with three polarizers]

Example with three polarizers (25% transmission).

A quick simulation shows that with 25 polarizers you already have 90% probability of transmission. With 247 you can get to 99%, but at this point you may better be using an optically active solution as others have suggested (which intrinsically uses this principle).

Comment: You can skip the one filter that aligns with the initial polarisation, giving you one more filter to use for smaller angle change.

Comment: I think about something very thin say 2-3cm and which I can buy e.g.optial element.

Comment: @Mercury This IS very thin. The layers are each noticeably thinner than a credit card, and relatively cheap material. And don't really need space between the layers, even though it looks like it in the illustration.

Answer (score 1):

To flip polarization between vertical and horizontal, a half wave plate is good. For arbitrary angles, the [Faraday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect) is commonly employed, especially if adjustable rotation is required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a half-waveplate designed for the appropriate wavelength can be used to rotate the orientation of linearly polarized light. The half wave plate is a linear device so the frequency of light going in is the same as the frequency of light going out, the energy of the photons is unaffected. There might be a small amount of power losses (this means losing photons, not photons changing their energy) due to reflection, absorptions and scattering. Easily less than 10% or 5% probably.